# Use of undeclared identifier "FlurryAPI"

Tags: ios, xcode, import, flurry

I already have analytics enabled and working.

I have added:

```
#import "FlurryAdDelegate.h"
#import "FlurryAppCircle.h"
#import "FlurryOffer.h"
#import "FlurryAnalytics.h"
```

this line throws this error:

> Use of undeclared identifier "FlurryAPI":

```
[FlurryAPI setAppCircleEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: Can we see where FlurryAPI was declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right call for that is `[FlurryAppCircle setAppCircleEnabled:YES];`

I don't think there's a `FlurryAPI` class at all.

See [sample code](http://support.flurry.com/sdkdocs/iOS/interface_flurry_app_circle.html#a239d70786e6a62e5cedde85fcb37b8b6) at the Flurry documentation site.

Comment: this is where i got the bad code: https://dev.flurry.com/appCirclePublisherIntegrateSDKWizard.do?projectID=151248

Comment: @rowdyruckus, wow--definitely worth letting support@flurry.com know about that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you imported the class that has FlurryAPI? Did you follow all the instructions for flurryAPI? If that was all you needed to import you most likely need to create a string (or whatever flurry uses!)

Another thing is, you could have possibly forgot to import the framework!